# Get the Node value from XML

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

How do I use [XPathNavigator.Evaluate](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Xml.XPath/types/XPathNavigator.html#Evaluate(System.String)) ( or other methods in XPathNavigator) to obtain the ISBN value for the following xml input?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
<bookstore xmlns:bk="urn:samples">
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1997" bk:ISBN="1-861001-57-8">
    <title>Pride And Prejudice</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Jane</first-name>
      <last-name>Austen</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>24.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1992" bk:ISBN="1-861002-30-1">
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Margaret</first-name>
      <last-name>Atwood</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>29.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1991" bk:ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>Emma</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Jane</first-name>
      <last-name>Austen</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1982" bk:ISBN="1-861001-45-3">
    <title>Sense and Sensibility</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Jane</first-name>
      <last-name>Austen</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given by amdfan is almost correct. Here's the correct syntax:

```
XPathIterator xit = XPathNavigator1.Select("/bookstore/book/@bk:ISBN");
xit.MoveNext();
String value = xit.Current.Value;
```

I tested this in VS 2008.

Answer (score 3):

```
XPathIterator xit = XPathNavigator1.Select("/bookstore/book/@bk:ISBN");
xit.MoveNext();
String value = xit.Current.Value;
```

The value you want is in `xit.Current.Value`

By the way, I recommend you check out [this great article](http://www.aspnetpro.com/newsletterarticle/2004/04/asp200404bn_l/asp200404bn_l.asp) on xPath.

Comment: The syntax is almost correct-- It should be XPathNavigator1.Select("/bookstore/book/@bk:ISBN");

Comment: Yeah, I was in a hurry and didn't test it